# How is Memcached Source Code Multithread safe on Multicore System (1.6.6)

Tags: c, multithreading, memcached, multicore

I was wondering how the memcached source code is multithread safe in a multicore enviornement, when the manipulation of many of the _stritem or item structs variables don't seem to utilize a lock when manipulated (instead using refcount to indicate how many threads are using the item).

Line: 519 in memcached.h

```
typedef struct _stritem {
    /* Protected by LRU locks */
    struct _stritem *next;
    struct _stritem *prev;
    /* Rest are protected by an item lock */
    struct _stritem *h_next;    /* hash chain next */
    rel_time_t      time;       /* least recent access */
    rel_time_t      exptime;    /* expire time */
    int             nbytes;     /* size of data */
    unsigned short  refcount;
    uint16_t        it_flags;   /* ITEM_* above */
    uint8_t         slabs_clsid;/* which slab class we're in */
    uint8_t         nkey;       /* key length, w/terminating null and padding */
    /* this odd type prevents type-punning issues when we do
     * the little shuffle to save space when not using CAS. */
    union {
        uint64_t cas;
        char end;
    } data[];
    /* if it_flags & ITEM_CAS we have 8 bytes CAS */
    /* then null-terminated key */
    /* then " flags length\r\n" (no terminating null) */
    /* then data with terminating \r\n (no terminating null; it's binary!) */
} item;
```

Line 851 in memcached.h

```
#define refcount_incr(it) ++(it->refcount)
#define refcount_decr(it) --(it->refcount)
```

Wouldn't a lack of locking on the item locks when incrementing/decrementing the variable structure in a multithreaded multicore environment potentially create a race condition?

For example: the variable could be fetched by both threads and placed in separate registers, then incremented in both registered, then replaced back in their memory location. This would cause a increment of only 1. Then if 1 thread decremented, couldn't the object be freed and then cause a problem for the other thread?

Edit: To clarify, given memcached has existed for 17 + years the implementation is most likely bug-free, but I am curious as to how memcached handles this.